# UIActivityViewController: access the navigation items to change color of presented view

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiactivityviewcontroller, tintcolor

I am changing a project colors and this *old orange color* not changed on *UIActivityViewController button*. I want to change button color orange to white.
This look is when user press the share button and select "*Add to Notes*" button. How can I access these buttons and change colors?

[image: Add to Notes Screen]

First problem solved. This code is working on buttons:

```
UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor = .white
```

---

When I click to "*New Note*" this look is came. **How can I change the title color on this view?**
I want to change this title color **black to white**.

[image]

This is my sharing code and I was trying every bar tint color code.

```
func shareLink(_ link: String) {
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [link], applicationActivities: nil)

    activityViewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
    activityViewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
    activityViewController.tabBarController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .white
    activityViewController.tabBarController?.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Also I tried adding some code on **AppDelegate** in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.tintColor = .white
```

Comment: @KSigWyatt No, it's not possible. I don't know where I can access this button and I ask it.

Comment: Did you try something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47060512/6448167

Comment: @KSigWyatt No, I didn't try. It worked, but I asked how I could access those buttons.

Comment: These buttons are not accessible. Apple generates the buttons within this controller based on the localization of the client device. As https://stackoverflow.com/a/15294107/6448167 this answer suggests you may be able to override and generate your own `UIActivityViewController` in order to change / access the contents of the buttons in the controller's navigation bar.

Comment: @KSigWyatt Ok. Thanks, but when i click to "New Note" some black title came. How can I change color too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. These buttons are not accessible. So I solved the problem as follows:

It's for all UINavigationBar buttons:

```
UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor = .white
```

It's for all UINavigationBar titles:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
```